# Linq: Convert IEnumerable<Point> to an IEnumerable<float>

Tags: c#, linq

I have an **`IEnumerable<Point>`** and I want to convert it to an **`IEnumerable<float>`**.

Can I do this in a single Linq statement?

```
IEnumerable<float> ConvertToPoints(IEnumerable<Point> points)
{
    List<float> floats = new List<float>();
    foreach(var point in points)
    {
        floats.Add(point.X);
        floats.Add(point.Y);
    }
    return floats;
}
```

Comment: Just after adding the question, I came up with IEnumerable<float> floats = points.SelectMany(p => new float[] {p.X, p.Y} );

Comment: To insert code, just indent it four spaces. No need to do all the HTML markup yourself.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx):

```
return points.SelectMany(point => new float[] { point.X, point.Y });
```

Another way that doesn't require LINQ is to use an iterator block:

```
IEnumerable<float> getPoints(IEnumerable<Point> points)
{
    foreach (Point point in points)
    {
        yield return point.X;
        yield return point.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: My immediate response would have been the SelectMany, but that iterator block code looks pretty sweet!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can also do the inverse - convert a list of floats to a list of PointF structures (piggybacking off of Mark's answer):

```
IEnumerable<PointF> AsPointF(this IEnumerable<float> ordinates) 
{ 
    float x;
    float y;

    int i = 0;

    foreach (float f in ordinates) 
    {
      switch (i)
      {
        case 0:
          x = f;
          i++;
        break;
        case 1:
          y = f;
          i = 0;
          yield return new PointF(x, y);
        break;
      }
    }
} 

IEnumerable<float> ordinates = GetOrdinatesFromSomewhere();
IEnumerable<PointF> points = ordinates.AsPointF();
```